# How to get columns with specific string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2014 and below is my database with which I am working on and need some analysis done on it.

[image]

Upon inspecting the database sample carefully we can notice a number `8777` in `L9` and in `L13` column.

Now I want to get only those columns which have 8777 in them and in the end a column named "count" which shows how many times the number appeared means I need in output something like this as shown below:

[image]

So far I have written this query which is giving the category and subcategory correct. But it is showing all the columns. I have no idea how to count the occurrences of a number and show its count in a count column.

```
select * 
from Sheet2$
where '8777' IN ([L1],[L2],[L3],[L4],[L5],[L6],[L7],[L8],[L9],[L10],[L11],[L12],[L13]
```

[image]

Comment: A SQL query has a fixed number of columns.  In order to get a variable number of columns, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically limit the columns, you would need Dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Select *
 Into #Temp
 From  YourTable A
Unpivot ( Value for Item in ([L1], [L2],[ L3], [L4], [L5], [L6], [L7], [L8], [L9], [L10], [L11], [L12], [L13]) ) u
Where Value = 8777


Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Item) From #Temp  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select *,[Count] = sum(1) over()
 From  #Temp A
 Pivot (max(Value) For [Item] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

```
Category    SubCategory L13     L9      Count
C1          SC1         NULL    8777    2
C1          SC3         8777    NULL    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.   I think you want the original rows with the count.  I think this is:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @cols = (select distinct ', ' + v.colname
             from t cross apply
                  (values ('l1', l1),
                          ('l2', l2),
                          ('l3', l3),
                          ('l4', l4),
                          ('l5', l5),
                          ('l6', l6),
                          ('l7', l7),
                          ('l8', l8),
                          ('l9', l9),
                          ('l10', l10),
                          ('l11', l11),
                          ('l12', l12),
                          ('l13', l13)
                   ) v(colname, val)
             where v.val = '8777'
             for xml path ('')
            );

set @sql = '
select category, subcategory' + @cols + ',
       count(*) over () as cnt
from t
';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

The only difference from your result is that the count is on every row.  That can easily be adjusted using a `case` expression, but I'm not sure it is necessary.

If you want the count in only one row, then:

```
set @sql = '
select category, subcategory' + @cols + ',
       (case when row_number() over (order by category, subcategory) = 1
             then count(*) over ()
        end) as cnt
from t
order by category, subcategory
';
```

Comment: but it is showing all the columns and I need only L9 and L13 displayed in result

Comment: @zainulabidin . . . Just select the columns you want to display.

Comment: @zainulabidin . . . I totally rewrote the answer.  I like John's answer, but I think he misinterpreted the question (but of course, I might have as well).

Comment: I can't select the columns because the number can appear in any column, John is giving 90% right answer except that he is showing count as 2,2 in both the rows and I am not able to understand the code he has written

Answer (score 0):

You can try this part as a replacement of John's answer's second query to get the proper count, it does not achieve the exact thing you want but can be a work around.

```
Declare @sql varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Item)
From #Temp  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
print @sql;
Select  @SQL = '
Select *,value=8777
From  #Temp A
Pivot (Count(Value) For [Item] in (' + @sql + ') ) p'
print @sql;
Exec(@SQL);
```

I just used count function in pivot in place of sum.